# When should I get an oil change if I drive infrequently?

Tags: oil-change

I drive a 1997 Honda Accord maybe 6,000 miles each year. In past years, I've driven about 12,000 miles per year and changed the oil about every 3,000-4,000 miles, or about every three months.

When should I get my oil changed now that I'm driving less? Should it be by mileage (~six months) or do I need it changed earlier than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accordng to this [Honda Maintenance Calculator](http://www.honda.ca/owners/honda-services/maintenance-calculator), you should be changing it every 3 months.  At least, if you live in Canada.

If you're interested in reducing the change interval, consider going to a full synthetic oil which, depending on formulation (and marketing) would probably be good for [6 months to a year between changes.](http://www.mobiloil.com/USA-English/MotorOil/Car_Care/AskMobil/Recommended_Oil_Change_Intervals.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't drive a vehicle frequently enough and long enough, moisture will get into the oil.  Following the manufacturers spec for mileage and time is usually a good idea, every X miles or Y months, whichever you hit first.

First thing I do with my summer car when it comes out of the garage for the season is an oil change, regardless of the mileage on the oil (which usually isn't much).

Comment: I'd like more info on the moisture getting in. What factors are involved? How does it get in? Are there any other reasons behind oil changes every x months?

Comment: @MorganTiley This would be best posted as a question so everyone would see it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if we use different grades of oil, but most UK spec cars I have dealt with have had an oil change interval of 6 months, not 3, and some have been longer than that - more and more newer cars tend to be going towards 12months or 10-15000 miles

Answer (score 0):

I have a 1997 Accord and I still have the original owner's manual.  According to the Maintenance Schedule in the manual:

- Under [normal conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI2Dl.png) and occasional severe conditions, you should change the oil every 7500 miles or 12 months (whichever comes first).
- Under frequent [severe conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK9ZF.png) or if you live in Canada, you should change the oil every 3750 miles or 6 months (whichever comes first).  See the linked image for a list of things that constitute "severe conditions".